How to target and set a variable using a full data path contained in a string
I'm trying to create dynamic 'full data paths' to Geometry Node vars in a loop but I can't figure out how to call the result in Python.
Q: How to use the resulting concatenated string to target and set the variable it references?
I'm sure it's a very basic question.
Most of the demo results I find are system paths to open a file, but I only want to set variables.
Here is an example full data path and code snippet that concatenates those paths
#bpy.data.objects["panel.000"].modifiers["GeometryNodes"]["Socket_2"] = 10

panelVar = "panel.000"

 targetPath = 'bpy.data.objects["' + panelVar + '"].modifiers["GeometryNodes"] ["Socket_2"]'

#how to use the targetPath to set variable here



Use path_resolve instead of eval/exec
import bpy

panelVar = "panel.000"
targetPath = 'bpy.data.objects["' + panelVar + '"].modifiers["GeometryNodes"] ["Socket_2"]'

def set_path_value(full_dp, value):
    full_dp = full_dp.strip()
    if full_dp.endswith(']'):
        i = full_dp.rfind('[')
        attr0 = full_dp[9 : i].strip() # path_resolve not allow extra space
        attr1 = full_dp[i : ].strip()
        
        parent = bpy.data.path_resolve(attr0)
        parent[attr1[2 : -2]] = value
    else:
        i = full_dp.rfind(".")
        attr0 = full_dp[9 : i].strip()
        attr1 = full_dp[i + 1 : ].strip()
        
        parent = bpy.data.path_resolve(attr0)
        setattr(parent, attr1, value)

set_path_value(targetPath, 0)

try: # Update UI
    bpy.context.object.data.update()
except:
    pass


I think you're overcomplicating this, you can try :
import bpy

panel_names = ["panel.000","panel.001","panel.002"]

for panel_name in panel_names:
    obj = bpy.data.objects.get(panel_name)
    target = obj.modifiers["GeometryNodes"]["Socket_2"]
    do_something(target)


Gorgious
Thanks!  That is a much more elegant solution.
But the part I most need resolved is "set a variable with the resulting path."
Such as brackets or another enclosing markup.  Pseudocode example:  self[target] = x
If I write target = x it will simply replace the path string with the value of x.
There must be some simple way to tell python the path is a pointer to a variable.

I'm sorry but I don't understand, if you want to store a string you can just store that ?

Here's what I want to achieve but in a loop so I don't have to write out each address.
bpy.data.objects["panel.000"].modifiers["GeometryNodes"]["Socket_2"] = 10
becomes
targetPath = 10
Maybe I just need to cast it as a different type, a string to path converter.

I'm going to try this from another forum:
from pathlib import Path
str_path = "my_path"
path = Path(str_path)

Haha sorry I still don't understand what's the end goal here ?
